# Linear Programming - deriving the Dual of the Primal

Tags: linear-programming, approximation

I've the following linear programming problem:
[image]

This is the LP representation of the uncapacitated facility location problem.

This is the dual representation of this problem:
[image]

My question is how to derive the dual representation from the primal in this problem.

I tried to follow the step by step tutorial by S´ebastien Lahaie found [here](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/coms6998-3/lpprimer.pdf)
but it won't work because of the summation in the constraint equations.

I'm looking for a pure mechanical way (with no intuition) to do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math problem not a programming one

Answer (score 0):

The step by step tutorial actually works quite fine. It looks like I've lost a sign somewhere, but the fourth step will produce:

[image: 1]

Where did I get it? I just multiplied the [image: 2] constraint by [image: 3] and added it to the objective clause for every j, then I did the same with the other constraint.

Now I just group the terms by the primal variables. What I get is basically:

[image: 4]

**note** that I use i implicitly for the set F and j for the set D. And sorry for the bad formatting.